# Which library is 'WL' in the following code

Tags: javascript

For authentication using chrome, I am following this repo and this specific file : https://github.com/jameslau-MSFT/MSAuthFromChromeExtSample/blob/master/js/popup.js

However they have something 'WL'. I don't know where they got it. I looked at .gitignore (there is none).

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In https://github.com/jameslau-MSFT/MSAuthFromChromeExtSample/blob/master/html/popup.html you can see a script imported: `<script src="https://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>`. This seems to be the culprit.

Googling "wl.js" then took me to here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh550837.aspx - turns out it's the JavaScript library for the Microsoft Live API. (WL = "Windows Live" I assume).

Comment: Ohhh, I keep on looking at their js folder. Thank you so much! Makes me feel silly

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the [Windows Live API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh550838.aspx):

> Makes a call to the Live SDK Representational State Transfer (REST)
>   API, for a Windows Store app or web app.

Here's how to [use the library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh550837.aspx) directly. That page includes instructions on [Referencing the JavaScript library in a web app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh550837.aspx#ref_web). Which gives the following example (which is in the HTML of the linked project):

```
<script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft Dev Center. Live SDK REST API.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243643.aspx):

> The WL object is a global object that encapsulates all functions of the Live SDK JavaScript API (Windows Store app and web). Your app uses the WL object to call all of the Live SDK JavaScript API functions.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search yielded that it's from the Windows Live SDK framework:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh550844.aspx

> The Live SDK JavaScript API (Windows Universal app and web) and the
>   REST API, enables apps to read, update, and share user data by using
>   JavaScript. It provides methods for signing users in and out, getting
>   user status, subscribing to events, creating UI controls, and calling
>   the Representational State Transfer (REST) API.